# Como validar que la fecha inicio no sea menor a la fecha final del registro anterior en Javascript o JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día quiero validar que mi fecha inicio no sea menor a mi fecha final del registro anterior con JavaScript, actualmente quería primero obtener la fecha final del registro anterior, pero no me lo hace, solo me trae el ultimo la ultima fecha del año, anexo código, espero puedan ayudar:

```
var dateFrom = moment(dateFrom).subtract(1, 'months').endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Saludos.

Comment: Estoy usando .net

Answer (score 0):

> quiero validar que mi fecha inicio no sea menor a mi fecha final

Para lograr esto (viendo que utilizas moment) puedes usar el método [isBefore](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/01-is-before/) o el método [isAfter](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/03-is-after/).

Esto sería:

```javascript
const fechaInicio = '2010-10-30';
const fechaFinal = '2010-10-20';

moment(fechaInicio).isBefore(fechaFinal); // false
moment(fechaInicio).isAfter(fechaFinal); // true
```

Comment: Buen día Andres, si esta bién lo que señalas en el código solo que no me trae la fecha final del registro anterior, no se si haya una forma de poner un -1 o usar un lenght, has de cuenta como un reverse o algo asi, por que actualmente con ese codigo me traigo la fecha inicio y fecha fin pero de mi registro actual como quien dice, y lo que requiero es que no me traiga la fecha final de mi registro actual si no la fecha final del registro anterior, dejo codigo para que veas como es que lo tengo.

Comment: Andres también hago un else if para validar las fechas como se muestra en el código, pero no se si este bien las validaciones que hago, espero puedas apoyarme.

Comment: Tomo de ejemplo el que pusiste const fechaInicio = '2010-10-30'; --- esta es fecha inicio del registro actual como quien dice
const fechaFinal = '2010-10-20'; ---- y esta es la fecha del registro anterior, lo que requiero tomando el ejemplo que pones es que la fecha inicio no sea menor a la fecha final del registro anterior usando esas fechas que pones has de cuenta que si modifico mi fecha inicio 2010-10-30 la hago menor a la fecha fina 2010-10-20, un dia menos por ejemplo que ahi me muestra el mensaje, pero siempre del registro anterior, no del  actual.

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz si te soy sincero, tu pregunta no es muy clara. Podrías por favor agregar el código que mencionas en la pregunta editándola? Recuerda que solo tu sabes de tú código, yo no se a qué te refieres cuando dices "registro anterior". Si puedes darme mas contexto y actualizar tu pregunta sería mas facil ayudarte.